# Give apache user permission to read directory

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, permissions, selinux

**UPDATE**:

Saw this question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/515243/why-cant-my-apache-process-write-to-my-world-writeable-file

Could this be SELinux related, currently /etc/sysconfig/selinux is setting to permissive:

```
SELINUX=permissive
```

**UPDATE**

Disabled SELINUX, no change.

Platform: This on CentOS 5.5, Apache 2

`ls -l` gives

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root mail 9230 Mar 2 10:25 2011 MyFile.txt
```

I need to give apache user read access to /var/MyApp directory.

I do:

```
chmod a+r /var/MyApp -R
```

And ls -l confirms that all file permissions have changed to allow any user to read.
But when I do this

```
sudo -u apache tail /var/MyApp/MyFile.txt
```

I get this error:

```
tail: cannot open `/var/MyApp/MyFile.txt' for reading: Permission denied
```

Does apache user require some special configuration to allow read access?

Comment: You forgot to mention the platform.

Comment: @Ignacio: updated

Comment: your file have correct permission ? (file not folder)

Comment: @Efazati: Yes, question has been updated with `ls -l` showing file permission

Comment: Can the current user read the file, e.g. `tail /var/MyApp/MyFile.txt
`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be an execute bit problem on `/var` or `/var/MyApp`.  Make sure both `/var` and `/var/MyApp` are `chmod a+x`.  Also make sure that the apache user's shell isn't disabled (e.g., `/sbin/nologin` or `/bin/false`)

Answer (score 0):

No, but chmod, like many UNIX commands, doesn't like it when you put options after arguments. Put the `-R` before the `a+r` and see if that helps.

Comment: `ls -l` gives `-rw-rw-r-- 1 root mail   9230 Mar  2 10:25 2011 MyFile.txt`